Integral over unit sphere of radius vector tensor field
How do I solve the following two integrals over the unit sphere?
$$\iint_S \vec{r_0}\otimes\vec{r_0}dS \\ \iint_S \vec{r_0}\otimes\vec{r_0}\otimes\vec{r_0}\otimes\vec{r_0}dS$$
I undestand I should use the divergence theorem somehow but I'm not sure how.
My attempt at the first goes like:
$$\iint_S \vec{r_0}\otimes\vec{r_0}dS=\iint_S d\vec{S}\otimes\vec{r_0}=\iiint\nabla\otimes\vec{r_0}dV$$
And since we were integrating over the unit sphere we can(?) replace $\vec{r_0} \rightarrow \vec{r}$ so:
$$=\iiint\nabla\otimes\vec{r}dV=\iiint\hat{\delta}dV=\frac{4}{3}\pi\hat{\delta}$$
However I can't seem to use the same trick for more than two $r$'s multiplied with the tensor product since I get non-constant terms under the integral.

Ummm... what is $\vec{r_0}$?

It is the unit radius vector $\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$

Oh... so it is not a constant, then?  Such a subscript typically implies it is a constant.

Well  $\vec{r_0} \times \vec{r_0} = 0$ always.

those are tensor products. Not cross products

This post should help you figure things out.
